# Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext' C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know this is posted a lot but I couldnt find a solution for previous posts, not sure if its is because most target dotnet 3 and below but I am trying to run a migration for my database yet I still get this error: Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'.

What is unique is that I can run an update from the root folder if I run it like so:

```
 dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s API -p Persistence
 dotnet ef database update -s API -p Persistence
```

So I can get away with running this but I know its not right, I have a csproj file in my Persistence folder and I know I should be able to go into my Persistence folder and run a standard

```
dotnet ef migrations add OR dotnet ef database update
```

and it should run so I want to know what I am doing wrong.

**Program.cs**

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Persistence;

    namespace API;

   public class Program {

      public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
      var host =  CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

      using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();

      var services = scope.ServiceProvider;


      await host.RunAsync();
}

     public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Persistence;
using Application;

namespace API;

public class Startup
{

private readonly IConfiguration _config;
public Startup(IConfiguration config)
{
    _config = config;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
    });
    services.AddLogging();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
    });

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPIv5 v1"));
    }
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

}

**Data Context**

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Persistence;
   public class DataContext : DbContext
   {
     public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
     {
     }
  
      public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
   }
```

**AppSettings.Development**

```
 {
   "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
},
   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=AuthorizeNet.db"
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SqlLite or Sql Server? Looks like your DbContext is referencing EF but your startup setup is for SqlLite.